# how to apply css property to my first div class only

Tags: html, css

[image]I am having two **dhx_scroll_cont** div class, when i write css code as bellow it working for two classes. Now i want to write a css code that apply for first div call

```
.dhx_scroll_cont:before{
    //some code here
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/7xFDH/2/)

Simply use:

```
.dhx_scroll_cont:first-of-type:before{
    //some code here
}
```

[more on `first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type)

> The :first-of-type CSS pseudo-class represents the first sibling of
>   its type in the list of children of its parent element.

---

**Update**

According to [the screenshot the OP posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOtES.png) the below should work:

```
.dhx_view_day_events .dhx_scroll_cont:first-of-type:before{
    //some code here
}
```

Comment: @RaviVarma - this should work given the code you've provided, can you give some more CSS, HTML or a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: there is a catch though, if the class has been applied to different tags (div, p, section), then http://jsfiddle.net/7xFDH/1/

Comment: @Ejay - if you take the OP's provided code, the class is by itself, the provided jsFiddle was for illustration of `first-of-type` only

Comment: Yes it is pretty much context dependent but better than `:first-child`. I was trying to add some **more** usefulness to the answer (you've my upvote) :)

Comment: @Ejay - you have a point, it may be better for me to use classes in the example :)

Comment: You shouldbe able to use: `.dhx_view_day_events .dhx_scroll_cont:first-of-type:before` as the selector

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the structure of your HTML the solution you require will change.

Would you be able to provide the HTML structure for us to work from?

Otherwise, you could:

**Add another class to the div you want to change**

By having `<div class="dhx_scroll_cont">` you are only giving one targetable class. One way around this is having 2 classes separated by a space, such as:

`<div class="dhx_scroll_cont OTHER_CLASS">`

This will allow you to target the class `OTHER_CLASS` with the certain CSS values that you want effecting the first div.

**Using `:first-child` or `:first`**

`:first-child` and `:first` allow you to target the div that is the first child element of it's parent. For example:

```
<div class="surround">
    <div class="dhx_scroll_cont">

    </div>
    <div class="dhx_scroll_cont">

    </div>
</div>

dhx_scroll_cont:first-child {
    CSS HERE
}
```

This will effect the first `dhx_scroll_cont` div.

As I said previously, if you can give some more information on the structure of your HTMl it would help us with your solution.

### EDIT

---

Thanks for showing the HTML structure.

With that structure out of the methods that I have shown, adding another class to the first of the `dhx_scroll_cont` will allow you to specifically target that div, and not the other one.